# Отличие "картинок с сюрпризом" от обычных изображений.

Tags: изображения

На создание данного поста меня вдохновило [это](http://traditio-ru.org/wiki/RARJPEG), [это](http://pikabu.ru/story/rarjpeg_kak_sredstvo_obmena_faylami_1621635) и [это](https://hpc.name/thread/47810/p1.html).
Если эти rarjpeg'и можно создать, значит можно и определить их среди обычных "невинных" изображений. Под подозрение сразу попадают .jpg и .png. А как же отличить раржпег от обычной картинки?

Банальное сравнение размера (если, например, картинка больше 10 Мб, то она может быть раржпегом) не поможет - могут быть разные размеры: картинка 10Кб с спрятанным в ней однострочным текстовиком или большая фотография с довольно большим аудиофайлом внутри. Как бы вы отличили?

Я бы сделал так: расчитываем размер изображения (`высота*ширина*глубина_цвета`) и сравниваем его с настоящим размером файла. Не сошлось - значит раржпег. Но как же тогда расчитать размер EXIF и сжатие (у jpg), они же тоже часть изображения?

**UPDATE** Написал рабочий (довольно шустрый) алгоритм на Java (проверял на Android'e). Спокойно работает с png+zip/rar, jpg+zip/rar.

```
//Определим заголовки файлов
String HEADER_RAR = "Rar!"; //Для .rar это будет Rar!
String HEADER_ZIP = new String(new BigInteger("504B0304", 16).toByteArray()); //а для .zip будет "PK" и ещё два нечитаемых символа, поэтому мы получим их из HEX-кода

//создаём массив строк с путями к нужным изображениям (ArrayList<String> mImages)
ArrayList<String> mRarjpegs = new ArrayList<String>(); //массив с путями к раржпегам

for (String path : mImages) { //проверяем каждый файл
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) //открываем файл построчно...
            {
                if (line.contains(HEADER_RAR) || line.contains(HEADER_ZIP)) // ...если в строке нашёлся заголовок одного из архивов...
                    {
                        mRarjpegs.add(path); // ...то добавим его в список раржпегов
                        break; // ...и выйдем из цикла, чтобы не считывать остальную часть файла
                    }
                }
    } catch (Exception ex) { /* что-то своё */ }
}
//На выходе получим mRarjpegs, наполненный путями
```

Comment: Интересный фокус, не знал! Определять просто: быть одной из программ. Искать заголовок RAR-архива дальше, чем несколько байт от начала файла., или [метку окончания JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure) (`0xFF, 0xD9`) далеко до конца файла.

Facebook и ВКонтакте загружаемые картинки пересэмплируют, поэтому там RAR-часть не пройдёт. Так что призагрузке изображений можно их пережимать GD или ImageMagick'ом, чтобы не пропустить лишнего.

Comment: А поиск заголовка/метки в одном файле займёт много времени? А что если требуется проверить, например, 100 файлов на наличие архива внутри?

Comment: Нужно прочитать в худшем случае весь файл, отыскивая последовательность из двух байт. Не должно быть дольше, чем просто скопировать один раз все эти файлы, скажем.

Answer (score 3):

Я когда-то писал для себя подобное. Вроде работает.

```
enum RJClassification
{
    NotJpeg,
    JustJpeg,
    JpegWithUnrecognizedTail,
    JpegWithRarTail
}

static class RJClassifier
{
    public static RJClassification Classify(byte[] data, out long payloadIndex)
    {
        payloadIndex = 0;
        JpegParser jpp = new JpegParser(data, 0);
        if (!jpp.HasJpegHeader())
            return RJClassification.NotJpeg;
        var jpegEnd = jpp.SkipJpegHeader();
        if (!jpegEnd.HasValue)
            return RJClassification.NotJpeg;
        var rrp = new RarParser(data, jpegEnd.Value);
        var rarStart = rrp.FindRarHeader();
        if (!rarStart.HasValue)
            return RJClassification.JpegWithUnrecognizedTail;
        payloadIndex = rarStart.Value;
        return RJClassification.JpegWithRarTail;
    }
}

class RarParser
{
    byte[] data;
    long startIndex;
    public RarParser(byte[] data, long startIndex)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
    }

    byte[] signature = { 0x52, 0x61, 0x72, 0x21, 0x1A, 0x07, 0x00 };
    public long? FindRarHeader()
    {
        // state machine
        int state = 0;
        for (long i = startIndex; i < data.LongLength; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] == signature[state])
            {
                state++;
                if (state == signature.Length)
                    return i + 1 - state;
            }
            else
            {
                if (state > 0)
                    i--; // need to recheck the current byte
                state = 0;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

JPEG parser чересчур длинный, положил [сюда](http://pastebin.com/4K2KAzAX).

Для других форматов картинок нужен, понятно, другой картиночный парсер. Или можно вообще без него, если скармливать `RarParser`'у ноль в качестве `startIndex` (но будет дольше и менее надёжно).

---

Упс, кажется, код никогда не возвращает `JustJpeg`. Нужна ещё проверка после var `jpegEnd = jpp.SkipJpegHeader();`.

Comment: Хороший пример, плюсанул. Наверно тоже стоит что-то написать :)

Comment: @SuperCreeper: спасибо!